# Is PHP truly faster on the JVM?

Tags: php, jvm, resin

Lately I've been hearing a lot of people evangelizing that PHP with Resin is actually much faster than with mod_php, but I cannot find any benchmark anywhere.

Is it true or just vendor BS?

Answer (score 2):

InfoQ has [this video presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/nicholson-php-jvm) from the 2008 JVM Language Summit on "P8, an implementation of PHP on the JVM. Topics covered include the reasons for bringing PHP to the JVM, an overview of PHP and P8 ..."

From what I've heard so far, performance was a topic of much discussion at the Summit, but I haven't had time to get through this presentation yet. However, I don't have any trouble believing that PHP source compiled into JVM bytecode and then run on a hot-spotting JVM would outperform a pure interpretation-based implementation.